# Revtex4 separate title and abstract page

Tags: spacing, formatting, sectioning, titles, page-breaking

I am writing a paper using Overleaf and Revtex4. However, I need the title and the abstract to have their own separate pages. I have a very bashy solution of adding \vspace{30cm} before the abstract content, but this doesn't center the title or abstract in the center of their respective pages, and the abstract section is not clearly labeled with a section header.

Is there a way to separate the title and abstract such that they will sit in the middle of their respective pages instead of at the top?
Here is my code so far:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}
\affiliation{Somewhere}

\begin{abstract}
\vspace{30cm}
Your abstract.
\vspace{30cm}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the heading of the abstract is set by \frontmatter@abstractheading via the class options you have not shown to be in the style of whichever journal is being used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\begin{group}...\end{group}` or I remember `\begin{center}...\end{center}`

Comment: \begin{center}...\end{center}

Comment: have you tested this at all?  what do you expect `\begin{group}` to do?????

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I want to vertically center the abstract and title page such that they are not at the top of their respective pages. For example, I'd like them to look like the abstract and title page of the University of Miami thesis template. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-miami-thesis-template/hnqdhpwvwvcm